# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I put the script on the page, but I got this error ?

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds

`driver.set_script_timeout()` doesn't help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()

options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.apple.com/")
driver.set_script_timeout()
driver.execute_async_script("""const script = document.createElement('script'); script.id = '__table_iac'; script.dataset.shortCode = '97sqKm'; script.src = 'https://concierge.table.co/static/widget/inappchat.js';; document.body.appendChild(script);""")
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `driver.set_script_timeout()` as blank, is it your actual code or a typo?

Comment: driver.set_script_timeout() is by default 30 seconds, I put there 60, but it still doesn't work. But script appears on the page, and I can manipulate with the script, but any further code doesn't work.

Comment: @DebanjanB, do you think there is a problem with js code ?

Comment: I will take a fresh look at your question tomorrow. By the meantime can you confirm that the JS is perfect and what is the expected result of executing the JS?

Comment: I am not sure for JS code, I copied the code from somewhere. - @DebanjanB

Comment: So what is the expected result of executing the JS? Is it absolutely necessary to execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your async script doesn't return anything.

Selenium is expecting a callback to be triggered after the async script has completed.  If it doesn't get anything back after 30 seconds the script timeout kicks in and throws an error.

Instead of trying to run as an async script just try running it as a standard inline script.

```
driver.execute_script("""const script = document.createElement('script'); script.id = '__table_iac'; script.dataset.shortCode = '97sqKm'; script.src = 'https://concierge.table.co/static/widget/inappchat.js';; document.body.appendChild(script);""")
```